# Error of unexpected token import in react jest test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

My  `jest.config.js` file contains this data given below.

But when i am running test command it is giving me error of SyntaxError:

> Unexpected token import

Error i am getting when i fire test command

[image: e]

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
bail: true,
rootDir: process.cwd(),
testRegex: '/__tests__/.*\\.test\\.jsx?$',
transform: { '/__tests__/.*': path.resolve(__dirname, 'jest.transform.js'),},
verbose: true,
};
```

Comment: please  share your `jest.transform.js`

Comment: ``const babelJest = require('babel-jest');

module.exports = babelJest.createTransformer({
  presets: ['@babel/env'],
  plugins: [
    ['@babel/transform-runtime', { regenerator: true }],
  ]
});
``

Answer (score 0):

It typically happens when your tests and code are not processed by Babel. Jest is a Node.js application and Node.js doesn't understand `import` syntax.

I see that you defined your own `transform` config. [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#transform-object-string-string) says that if you set some value for `transform` config option it will overwrite defaults and Jest won't preprocess your code using babel-jest.
To fix this issue you need to explicitly define what files to transform via babel-jest:

```
transform: {
  '/__tests__/.*': path.resolve(__dirname, 'jest.transform.js'),
  "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
},
```

Comment: I have tried this and still, I am getting the same error.

Comment: The next place where can be the cause of such errors is `.babelrc`. If you turned off import processing via `modules: false` option for `babel-preset-env` or `babel-preset-es-2015` they won't be processed in tests too.
Could you please show the content of your `.babelrc` file?

Answer (score 0):

Please install `"babel-jest": "^23.0.1",` and add the following transform config:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
bail: true,
rootDir: process.cwd(),
testRegex: '/__tests__/.*\\.test\\.jsx?$',
"transform": {
  "\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
},
verbose: true,
};
```

Let me know if the issue still persists